# C# connection with SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

```
[WebMethod] 
public void RegisterStudent(string Name, string Gender, int Marks)        
{            
    string connectionString = 
           "Data Source =SAJID-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Design;Integrated Security=True";             
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);             
    con.Open();             
    String query = "INSERT INTO Students VALUES + ('" + Name + "', '" + Gender + "'," + Marks + ")";             
    SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();  
    con.Close();
}
```

I get this error when I invoke the method:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '+'.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   Assignment4Web.StudentService.RegisterStudent(String Name, String
>   Gender, Int32 Marks) in c:\users\sajid\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\Assignment4Web\Assignment4Web\StudentService.asmx.cs:line
>   56

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove unnecessary `+` after `Values` and add `'` around `Marks` like this:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('" + Name + "', '" + Gender + "','" + Marks + "')";
```

**Although** you **should** always use [`parameterized queries`](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [`SQL Injection`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Something like this:

```
SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Students VALUES(@Name ,@Gender,@Marks");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",Name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender",Gender);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Marks",Marks);
```